# Authenticating payfort using ruby net http code as provided by postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman, payfort

I am trying to authenticate payfort of server side in my rails app using Ruby Net Http, when i call their API in postman it works fine:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRnmg.png)

Then i take the code generated by postman from the following screen to include it in my rails app

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00hHl.png)

This is not working. I try running it in console and get this error:

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJZcw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I see that your URL is using HTTPS and postman has not added the following two lines in the generated code:

```
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

So your full code should look like this instead:

```
device_id = ‘your device id’
signature = ‘sha signature’
url = URI('https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
req.body = '{"access_code”:”asdasdasdsa”,”device_id":"'+device_id+'","language":"en","merchant_identifier”:”dsadasdasd”,”service_command":"SDK_TOKEN","signature":"'+signature+'"}'
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
res = http.request(req)
response =  JSON.parse(res.body)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. Glad to help!